# How to refer to a newly added element in jquery and set CSS style

Tags: javascript, jquery

The methods jQuery used to manipulate DOM like append()/after() all returns with this keyword, which refer to the original jQuery object in order for chaining.

```
var $test=$("#test").after("<div>test</div>");
$test.css("color","red");
```

It will send the #test element font color to red, not the newly created element.

Now say I want to immediately store the newly created element "test" to a variable the same as the original DOM way.

```
var test=document.createElement("div");
```

So later I can set the css style using:

```
test.style.color="red";
```

Of course I can mix the DOM way and jQuery way:

```
var test=document.createElement("div"); 
test.innerHTML="just a test";
$(#test).after(test);
$(test).css("color","red");
```

But is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

An option you have is to use [**`.insertAfter()`**](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) instead of `.after()`, as that'll return the element you just created:

```
var $test = $("<div>test</div>").insertAfter("#test");

$test.css("color","red");
```

You can also do it on the same line:

```
var $test = $("<div>test</div>").insertAfter("#test").css("color","red");
```

Other options:

```
var $test = $("<div style='color:red'>test</div>").insertAfter("#test");

var $test = $("<div>",{ style:"color:red",html:"test"}).insertAfter("#test");
```